# Is it right to say "hastening the time of my own doom"?

Tags: word-choice

Since hasten means accelerate, I feel the person is saying that he or she is saying shortening the time of his doom of making it pass away more quickly.

The correct way or what I think he is trying to say is "hastening the time before my doom comes"?

Not sure though, because my command of English is pretty bad, as I see it.

Comment: Not pass away, but come to pass.  Making the doom *arrive* more quickly.

Comment: @TimRomano, how come? I though he mean to accelerate or shorten the period of his doom?

Comment: Doom is a final irrevocable judgment.  It can be used figuratively to mean 'fate' or even 'death'.  It can be caused to arrive sooner, but it cannot be made shorter since it is not a "period". It has no duration.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it just be "hastening my doom"? The others seem redundant, and a strange turn of phrase (what does it mean to hasten a time?).

The thing being accelerated is the doom, not the time, no?